# Cambridge Admissions Exam 1987 Paper

Tags: classical-mechanics

The problem I am attempting is the following
[image]

I got pretty far into it, however, I was not able to do the last step of the solution.  The given solution is here

[image]

**What I don't understand:** I don't understand where  the last equation comes from. Can someone clarify where it comes from?

Comment: do you know about equilibrating moments ?

Comment: In the diagram, we are taking moments about an axis through the point of contact with the table, and perpendicular to the plane of the page. The left-hand side of the equation gives the clockwise component due to gravity, and the right-hand side gives the anticlockwise component due to the tension in the string.

Comment: @GCab no I have not. Is this what the answer is using? If yes do you know of any good resources through which I can learn about it?

Comment: yes, the answer is using that principle, and, well, that is a fundamental chapter of any course in [Statics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statics)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just the moment of force balance. In the statement of the problem, it's said that the distance from the axis to the center of mass is $\cfrac{3\pi a\sin \theta}{16\theta}$.

Basically, in the following formula $$F_1 l_1 = F_2 l_2$$ we have $F_1 = \cfrac{Mg\theta}{\pi}$,$~ l_1 =\cfrac{3\pi a\sin \theta}{16\theta}$ and $F_2 = 2T\sin \theta$, $~l_2 = a$.